# Button text will not toggle

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I've been reading my JS book and googling and messing with it for a couple hours but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

HTML

```
<button id="sidebarButton" class="sidebarButton" onclick="toggle()"> >> </button>
```

JS

```
function toggle() {
      if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML == " >> ") {
        document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML = " << ";
      } else if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML == " << ") {
        document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML = " >> ";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the text on an element according to the **toggle** principle, it is not necessary to use the `if {}` condition.

```js
function toggle(element) {
  element.innerText = element.innerText === '>>' ? '<<' : '>>';      
}
```

```html
<button id="sidebarButton" class="sidebarButton" onclick="toggle(this)">>></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggle() {
console.log(document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML)
      if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML == " &gt;&gt; ") {
        document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML = " << ";
      } else if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML == " &lt;&lt; ") {
        document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML = " >> ";
      }
    }
```

```html
<button id="sidebarButton" class="sidebarButton" onclick="toggle()"> >> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) . It'll work.

```
function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerText == ">>") {
    document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerText = " << ";
  } else if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerText == "<<") {
    document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerText = " >> ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is with the ">>" sign, ">" HTML has ">" signs already predefined, so when you write ">" you want to use an HTML entity `&gt;`or `&lt;` (greater than or less than signs)

```html
<button id="sidebarButton" class="sidebarButton" onclick="toggle()"> &gt;&gt; </button>
<script>

function toggle() {
      if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML == "&gt;&gt;") {
        document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML = " &lt;&lt; ";
      } else if (document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML == " &lt;&lt; ") {
        document.getElementById("sidebarButton").innerHTML = " &gt;&gt; ";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an element parameter to your function. Pass `this` as the parameter then use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to toggle the content.

```js
function toggle(element) {     
     //To demonstrate the html as interpreted bu javascript
     console.log(element.innerText);
     console.log(element.innerHTML);
     element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML == " &gt;&gt; " ? " << " : " >> ";
}
```

```html
<button id="sidebarButton" class="sidebarButton" onclick="toggle(this)"> >> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to toggle word then you need to put another id in that paragraph and than put it display='block'

```
function toggle(){
let para=document.getElementbyId('para');
if(para.style.display !='none'){
para.style.display='none';
}
else{
para.style.display='block';
}
```